# Movement of objects using electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetism

I just thought of a phenomena. That electromagnetic radiation has the capability to physically move objects. In theory, if all objects are made of atoms. And atoms have neutrons and protons at the center of the atom with moving electrons surrounding their respective orbitals. When an electromagnetic wave is incident on the atom. The distortion of the electron clouds distorts the electron proton dipole. If you move the electron cloud, theoretically the proton should move with it. So therefore you get a transmission of force from the radiation electric and magnetic fields to the atom of the object. Its similar to how if you have two weak magnetics of opposing poles separated by a material. If you apply a force on one magnetic the other magnetic experienced the same force momentarily. Has anyone investigated this idea?

Comment: Its very tricky to define a electric dipole when talking about quantum objects.

Comment: You cant just move electrons further away from the nucleus because the energy levels of electrons in a atom are discrete not continuous.

Comment: The energy levels are discrete yes, but when a wave is incident on an electron. The electrons is still able to move when the matched energy is different to that between discrete energy levels.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to do it not with wave but with photons, the impulse of a photon is $h/\lambda$, and you can reflect or absorb it and so transfer impulse. It was discovered long time ago and one could even accelerate a spaceship with very large reflecting sails.